# Keeping MySQL staging database on same server updated from production

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump, amazon-rds, mysql-5

I just migrated my MySQL 5.5.20 to Amazon RDS from MySQL on EC2. The one thing I'm having difficulty with is how to keep my staging database updated from production. Before, I just ran a nightly `mysqlhotcopy` to overwrite staging from production and all was well. However, RDS doesn't give me shell access so I think I need a pure SQL solution to avoid doing a `mysqldump` to another server, and then restoring back to the RDS server, which seems unnecessary since I just want to copy to database-to-database on the same server. I know RDS supports read replicas, but I need a writable replica, and I don't want to have to fire up another instance for my staging database, which doesn't see a lot of action.

What's the best way to accomplish a database-to-database copy on the same server in pure SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see mysqldump being a little pain in the neck because of transaporting data out and then in.

Let's say you are copying data from proddb to stagedb. Here is a query to create the script for lateral copying of every table:

```
select
concat
(
    'drop table if exists ',db2,'.',tbl,'; ',
    'create table ',db2,'.',tbl,' like ',db1,'.',tbl,'; ',
    'insert into  ',db2,'.',tbl,' select * from ',db1,'.',tbl,';'
)
from (select table_schema db1,table_name tbl
from information_schema.tables where table_schema='stack_dev') tbls,
(select 'stack_test' db2) dbname;
```

Just generate the script as a SQL text file and import the text file to the target server:

```
PROD_IP-10.1.2.20
STAG_IP=10.1.2.40
mysql -h${PROD_IP} -uusername -p --skip-column-names -A -e"select concat('drop table if exists ',db2,'.',tbl,'; ','create table ',db2,'.',tbl,' like ',db1,'.',tbl,'; ','insert into  ',db2,'.',tbl,' select * from ',db1,'.',tbl,';') from (select table_schema db1,table_name tbl from information_schema.tables where table_schema='stack_dev') tbls,(select 'stack_test' db2) dbname;" > /root/CopyFromProdToStage.sql
mysql -h${STAG_IP} -uusername -p -A < /root/CopyFromProdToStage.sql
```

This should work just fine for MyISAM. It should also work for InnoDB if there are no constraints. If there are constraints, you may have to disable them for the import session:

```
PROD_IP-10.1.2.20
STAG_IP=10.1.2.40
echo "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;" > /root/CopyFromProdToStage.sql
mysql -h${PROD_IP} -uusername -p --skip-column-names -A -e"select concat('drop table if exists ',db2,'.',tbl,'; ','create table ',db2,'.',tbl,' like ',db1,'.',tbl,'; ','insert into  ',db2,'.',tbl,' select * from ',db1,'.',tbl,';') from (select table_schema db1,table_name tbl from information_schema.tables where table_schema='stack_dev') tbls,(select 'stack_test' db2) dbname;" >> /root/CopyFromProdToStage.sql
mysql -h${STAG_IP} -uusername -p -A < /root/CopyFromProdToStage.sql
```

### **UPDATE 2012-03-09 17:14 EST**

I have a stored procedure that will accomplish this. Run the following only once:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS utility;
CREATE DATABASE utility;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `utility`.`CopyDB` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `utility`.`CopyDB` (sourceDB VARCHAR(64),targetDB VARCHAR(64))
TheStoredProcedure:BEGIN

    DECLARE found_count,ndx,ndx_last INT;
    DECLARE sqlcmd VARCHAR(1024);

    SELECT COUNT(1) INTO found_count
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = sourceDB;
    IF found_count = 0 THEN
        LEAVE TheStoredProcedure;
    END IF;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DBTablesToCopy;
    CREATE TABLE DBTablesToCopy
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        src  VARCHAR(64),
        tgt  VARCHAR(64),
        tbl  VARCHAR(64),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SQLScriptToCopyTables;
    CREATE TABLE SQLScriptToCopyTables
    (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        sqltext VARCHAR(1024),
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

    INSERT INTO DBTablesToCopy (src,tgt,tbl)
    SELECT sourceDB,targetDB,table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = sourceDB;

    INSERT INTO SQLScriptToCopyTables (sqltext) VALUES
    (CONCAT('DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ',targetDB));
    INSERT INTO SQLScriptToCopyTables (sqltext) VALUES
    (CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ',targetDB));
    SELECT MAX(id) INTO ndx_last FROM DBTablesToCopy;
    SET ndx = 0;
    WHILE ndx < ndx_last DO
        SET ndx = ndx + 1;
        INSERT INTO SQLScriptToCopyTables (sqltext)
        SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',tgt,'.',tbl,' LIKE ',src,'.',tbl)
        FROM DBTablesToCopy WHERE id = ndx;
    END WHILE;
    SET ndx = 0;
    WHILE ndx < ndx_last DO
        SET ndx = ndx + 1;
        INSERT INTO SQLScriptToCopyTables (sqltext)
        SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO ',tgt,'.',tbl,' SELECT * FROM ',src,'.',tbl)
        FROM DBTablesToCopy WHERE id = ndx;
    END WHILE;

    SELECT MAX(id) INTO ndx_last FROM SQLScriptToCopyTables;
    SET ndx = 0;
    WHILE ndx < ndx_last DO
        SET ndx = ndx + 1;
        SELECT sqltext INTO @stmt FROM SQLScriptToCopyTables WHERE id = ndx;
        PREPARE s1 FROM @stmt;
        EXECUTE s1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
    END WHILE;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

then anytime you feel like copying `stack_dev` to `stack_test`, do this:

```
call utility.copydb('stack_dev','stack_test');
```

and that's all.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works perfectly. I just posted a somewhat modified version to a gist: https://gist.github.com/2173103